# Unwanted Communication Reporting extension can't send network request

Tags: ios, sms, reporting

I am creating in the application support for the Unwanted Communication Reporting extension. All I found is this guide from Apple: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sms_and_call_reporting/sms_and_call_spam_reporting and i follow it.

I've done:

- Instantiates my ViewController from ILClassificationUIExtensionViewController.
- Calls controller’s prepare(for:) method to customize UI.
- Create button to notify the system when you have completed gathering information (setting setting isReadyForClassificationResponse property to true.)
- Configure classificationResponse(for:) method after pressing Done button.

I want to send a response over the network so I add an associated domain to extension by following this instruction: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/supporting-associated-domain and advises from interenet. 
(Apple documentation supporting associated domain screenshots: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxroa.png)

- Create file apple-app-site-association, use classificationreport instead of webcredentials when specifying the domains.

```
{
 "applinks": {
  "apps": [],
  "details": [
   {
    "appID": “XXXX.com.project.UnwantedCommunicationExtension",
    "paths": ["*"]
   }
  ]
 },
 "classificationreport": {
   "apps": ["XXXX.com.project.UnwantedCommunicationExtension"]
  }
}
```

- Add domain to the entitlement: https://i.stack.imgur.com/38qbn.png
- Specify the network endpoint’s address using the ILClassificationExtensionNetworkReportDestination key in extension’s Info.plist file: https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6lbf.png
- Create test server and sent the apple-app-site-association file to this server.

Debugging and proxying my app, it doesn’t send any requests to the server. I can’t find any information about what request type should be sent, what data type will the server receive. Can anyone help to find information about it? Maybe advice what I did wrong, what settings should be on the server?

Comment: did you find the solution to this?

Comment: Hey, did you find a solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Your `apple-app-site-association` should look like this (with app identifier, not with extension identifier):

```
{
 "classificationreport": {
   "apps": ["XXXX.com.project"]
  }
}
```